# Need the absolute path of an embedded URL

Tags: windows-api-code-pack

The URL https://i.mjh.nz/SamsungTVPlus/all.m3u8
downloads the file all.m3u8.

This file, all.m3u8 contains the line
https://i.mjh.nz/SamsungTVPlus/ATBB3100001RH.m3u8

This URL downloads the file playlist.m3u8

This file, playlist.m3u8 contains the line
../../../manifest/3722c60a815c199d9c0ef36c5b73da68a62b09d1/MysteryKrimi-AT-prod/0aa242ab-a3d1-4a98-b027-ff64a2fc7c43/0.m3u8

Can someone please help me with the absolute path of this path?

I have tried parsing the path is various ways. But was not successful.